# Python tkinter treeview fills x regardless of what I try

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to have a treeview displaying data on the right half of my window with another free portion on the left side that would have buttons and entry boxes. I have tried adding frames directly to the root but as soon as I add the treeview any of the frames, it immediately resizes and takes up the entire top portion of the screen regardless of what I do. The best explanation I can show is by using the PanedWindow where I made two panes on the left and right side of the screen using the following code:

```
class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

[....]

        panel_left=tk.PanedWindow(bd=2,bg='yellow')
        panel_left.pack(side='left',fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
        panel_right = tk.PanedWindow(bd=2, bg='orange')
        panel_right.pack(side='right', fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

which gave me this:
[panedwindow without treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spkbb.png)

then this happens when I attempt to add the treeview to the panel_right using the following code:

```
data_tree = ttk.Treeview(panel_right,columns=json_tree_columns, show="headings", )

panel_right.add(data_tree)
```

[panedwindow with treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E96DF.png)

I don't know how to keep the treeview constrained within the pane, i've tried putting it in a frame as well as adjusting the self.root.rowconfigure and columnconfigure but still the same thing occurs, i dont necessarily have to use a panedwindow but i just want it to be constrained to a specific portion of the screen and not the whole top half

Comment: Why do you use two `PanedWindow` instead of one?

Comment: @acw1668 i wanted to add specific elements to the other half of the screen and figured that was the only way to do it

Comment: You can use single `PaneWindow` which contains a frame at the left side and the treeview at the right side.

Comment: @acw1668 okay i tried that by doing: `
        panel_left=tk.PanedWindow(bd=2,bg='yellow',orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        data_tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root, columns=json_tree_columns, show="headings", )
        panel_left.add(data_tree)
        panel_left.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)` but it still makes the treeview take up the entire screen

Comment: You have put only a treeview into the PaneWindow, so it will take all the space.  You need to put another frame with required width before putting the treeview.